# windows phone 8.1 - api - sign up and login

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, httpclient

I have got problem with using HttpClient in Windows Phone 8.1 application. I'm new in this WP 8.1 class.

I write this code:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://testapiurl.com");

            var message = new
            {
                Name = "Test",
                Surname = "Test",
                Mail = "test@test.pl",
                Password = "test1234"
            };
            var json_object = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);

            HttpStringContent stringContent = new HttpStringContent(json_object.ToString(), UnicodeEncoding.Utf8, "application/json");

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(
                uri,
                stringContent);

            Debug.WriteLine(response);
```

After compilation and running I got message

```
StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 2, Content: Windows.Web.Http.HttpStreamContent, Headers:
{
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Server: Apache/2.4
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=100000
  Date: Mon, 17 Aug 2015 04:59:02 GMT
  X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.39
}{
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
}
```

In API help and examples I have information that in return it should be Status Code: 200 and name of created user. But I don't get it. Second thing is that when I push the second time the same code to create account I get back the same response. In help for API it should be error 409 conflict the same account already exist.

I don't know that this code is good, or am I missing big amount of code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

to get your response string. There will be everything from the actual response.
Your current code only writes the response headers and the content type.